# Django Stripe PaymentIntent

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, stripe-payments

I am trying to setup the paymentIntent API from Stripe but I can't seem to figure out the error I am getting. I followed along from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1oLdAPyuok&t=1414s

I have a react frontend which makes a request to my Django view:

```
try {
      const { data: clientSecret } = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/paymentIntent/", {
        amount: price * 100
      });
```

My view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import logging
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status, generics
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view



from django.conf import settings
import stripe


stripe.api_key = "pk_test_51HWMwZB5hTmoPZOBJd00GjCvDYUg"

@api_view(['POST'])
def payment(request):
    try:
        amount = request.body
        paymentIntent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount = amount,
            currency = "usd",
            # payment_method_types=['card'],
            # capture_method='manual',
            metadata={'integration_check': 'accept_a_payment'},
        ) 

        data = paymentIntent.client_secret

        return Response(data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except :
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I make the request it just says 400 Bad Request with no response data

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the actual error message you're getting, your server should log out the error in your `try-catch` block, as shown here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=python allowing you to better debug and troubleshoot as you build your integration.

Most likely, it is that you have set your **publishable key** as your stripe-python API key. Instead you need to initialize `stripe` with your **secret key**: https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication?lang=python

Comment: I just get an error message saying : 400 Bad Request. It instantly gives me the error message. I just fixed my stripe initialization with my secret key but It still gives same error

Comment: There is an error message with the 400'ing request, look into your Stripe Dashboard logs at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs to see what the error message is, or log it out in your try-catch block